# Angular ngModel inside input and ngFor don't work and list the last elemnt of table

Tags: arrays, angular, input, ngfor, ngmodel

"I try to display element of an array inside  input using ngFor and ngModel
this is my HTML"

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let type of res;let in = index">
        <td><img src="assets/images/svg/line-delete.svg" matTooltip="Supprimer l'élement"></td>
        <td><input type="text" formControlName="texteListe"  name="name{{in}}" 
                  [(ngModel)]="type.TEXTE"></td>
        <td><input type="number" formControlName="valeurListe"  name="name{{in}}" 
                  [(ngModel)]="type.VALEUR">{{type.VALEUR}}</td>
        <td><i class="material-icons" (click)="champUp(type, in)">expand_less</i></td>
        <td><span class="material-icons" (click)="champDown(type, in)">expand_more</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let libelle of list; let in = index">
        <td *ngIf="showCase"><img src="assets/images/svg/line-delete.svg" matTooltip="Supprimer 
                  (click)="deleteElement()"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

this is my ts :

```
this.configurationService.getTypeListe().toPromise().then(list => {
    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++ ) {
        if (list[j].NODEFCODEX === element.NOGENE) {
            this.res.push(list[j]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you are mixing template driven with reactive forms so I'd start from there e.g. picking one

Comment: how i can eliminate mixing template driven ? do you have any suggestion

Comment: yes, I'd start by reading angular docs on template driven and reactive forms. dont mean to be rude but there is no easy way, gotta read the docs